# Using RegExp to search for string process it and then remove it (pure JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a variable in Javascript containing text, for example:

```
<First random:23>
<Hi id:2 value:43/>
<Last random:33>
```

I want to search for this pattern, and I've used:

```
/<HI ID:[\d]+ VALUE:[\d]+\/>/i
```

then I want to remove this occurrence from the original string. How can I do that? After I want something like:

```
<First random:23>
<Last random:33>
```

This is for parsing data for a game, after being parsed once, the text isn't needed anymore. And leaving it there may slow down the performance of future RexExp matches. More text, more time to execute or so I think! I'm I wrong?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: how should it look like after removing occurence?

Comment: Did the regex pattern you show work? (Note: you don't need the square brackets around the `\d`.)

Comment: [`<Hi id:\d+ value:\d+\/>`](https://regex101.com/r/nG6qQ6/1) in global mode, but your's works as well: https://regex101.com/r/nG6qQ6/2